# Cannot figure out what is causing this error in Python

Tags: python, integer

I keep getting this TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable error. I'm stuck.

[image]
[image]

I've tried taking away and adding str and int in different places but nothing has worked at all.

Comment: `point1[0]` is an `int` so you cannot index into it with `point1[0][0]`, etc..

Comment: Wellcome to SO. please, do not post code as image. read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
def midform(point1, point2):
    x = (point1[0] + point2[0])/2
    y = (point1[1] + point2[1])/2
    print("Midpoint X:", x, "Y:", y)
```

Error: because `point1[0]` is in your case an integer and you try indexing on int.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am a tool and just realized what I did.